# code for lambda function, which increments the salary of employee field

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I faced problem in one condition. I want a lambda function code for this condition
lambda triggers s3 bucket object (uploaded csv fie (contain emp details(name,id,salary)). lambda trigger happens every day at 9 am. when trigger happens the salary increases by 100 everyday.

```
import json
import os
import boto3
import csv

def lambda_handler(event,  context):
key = 'key-name'
bucket = 'bucket-name'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3_resource.Object(bucket, key)

data = s3_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()

lines = csv.reader(data)
headers = next(lines)
print('headers: %s' %(headers))
for line in lines:
    #print complete line
    print(line)
    #print index wise
    print(line[0], line[1])
```

Comment: What issues have you faced? What have you tried? Or do you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: i want code,actually i dont know python also,i tried what is available in others blogs.

Comment: i knowhow to do and all,but problem is lambda function code